# How do you make it so that each page has its own CSS / body in reactJS + react-router + create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React and React-Router, and create-react-app so no webpack

so I have an index.js which pretty much routes all my components and react-router is imported, and my main component is app.js, so pretty much routed in index.js like this, also im including login.js routing

```
<Route exact={true} path="/" component={App} /> 
<Route path="/Login" component={Login}/>
```

Now inside app.js I have app.css imported

```
import '../css/app.css';
```

and Im rendering a div with a bunch of stuff in it

```
<div>
    stuff in here
</div>
```

So inside app.css, I have

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("../images/app/app_background.JPG");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  margin: 0;
}
```

So this works perfectly on the app, now when I add a similar css file for login with everything the same as app.css but with a different background-URL, that background overrides the background on app.css

So pretty much the login.css file is overwriting all the css in the app.css file, it seems to me that both app.css and login.css are made global when I import them into a component, they are injected to the head of index.html and it overrides one another

Can anyone share intuition on how to stop this from happening?